# How to query firestore using numerical indexes (startAfter)

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my react app I want to add firestore pagination using startAfter, the idea is that initially user sees 20 blogs, then if user selects a new page, I fetch the next "20*page_number" blogs. (for example if the user selects page 2, I need firestore to return documents starting from index 40 etc)
[image]

My code so far:

```
const limited_blogs = 20
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(0);
const [lastDocument, setLastDocument] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
    updateBlogs(currentPage);
  }, [currentPage]);

        
async function updateBlogs(page) {
    try {
      const querySnapshot = await db
        .collection("blogs")
        .orderBy(`created_at`, 'desc')
        .startAfter(lastDocument)
        .limit(limited_blogs)
        .get();

      const docs = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));

      // to record the last returned document 
      const lastDoc = querySnapshot.docs[querySnapshot.docs.length - 1];  
      setLastDocument(lastDoc);
     

      // to calculate the number of pages to display
      const totalDocs = await db.collection("blogs").get();
      const total = totalDocs.size;
      setTotalPages(Math.ceil(total / limited_blogs));
    

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

/function to handle page click 
function handlePageClick(page) {
    setCurrentPage(page);
  }


// function to render pages
function renderPages() {
    const pageNumbers = [];

    for (let i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
      pageNumbers.push(
        <span
          key={i}
          onClick={() => handlePageClick(i)}
        >
          {i}
        </span>
      );
    }

    return pageNumbers;
  }
```

but this code only returns the next 20 documents,and doesn't change according to the selected page.

I tried this:

```
const lastDoc = querySnapshot.docs[(page- 1) * limited_blogs];
```

but in this case I need to read db every time to get `querySnapshot.docs` and it just not a good solution for a larger data. Any advise is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you `console.log(lastDocument)` right before you run the query, does it show the document that you expect the query to start after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase [does not support Pagination in a classical way](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) as it is presented in you screenshot.

There are workarounds:

1. Firebase supports *page scrolling* fetch out of the box via `startAfter` function. You need to remember the last loaded document. Then pass it to a function to start loading from when a user scrolls at the end of the page:

   ```
    // const lastDoc = ...

    query(
      collection(db, "collection_name"),
      orderBy("some_field"),
      startAfter(lastDoc),
      limit(25)
    );
   ```
2. Firebase allows to use `>` query logic via `startAt` function.
   To properly paginate there is a need to [count all documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation) via the aggregate function:

   ```
   import { getCountFromServer, collection, where, query } from 'firebase/firestore';

   const col = collection(db, "collection_name");
   // also can be used with query
   const snapshot = await getCountFromServer(col);
   const countedDocs = snapshot.data().count);
   ```

   Number of pages will be `countedDocs/docsPerPage`.

   Then there is a need to store a custom sequential field within every document, for example, containing numbers `1,2,3,4,...`, let's call it `order_field`. Now it will be possible to make a query:

   ```
   const q = query(colRef, orderBy("order_field"), startAt(25), endAt(50));
   ```